# Fatal Error : Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getPdf()

Tags: magento-1.9

I am getting the following error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getPdf() on
> bool in
> /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Sales/Invoice.php:119
> Stack trace: #0
> /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Order/InvoiceController.php(489):
> Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Sales_Invoice->printAction() #1
> /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(437):
> Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_InvoiceController->printAction() #2
> /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(262):
> Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('print') #3
> /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(192):
> Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
> #4 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(381): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch() #5
> /var/www/html/app/Mage.php(729): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array) #6
> /var/www/html/index.php(80): Mage::run('default', 'store') #7 {main}
> thrown in
> /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Sales/Invoice.php
> on line 119

Answer (score 0):

Well that error indicates the class you are calling `getPdf()` on doesn't exist. If you check out app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Config.php (~ line 1352 (as of version 1.9.4.5)) specifically the `getModelInstance()` function, you can see that it only returns a boolean if the class doesn't exist or if there is a problem including the file (in the `new $className` area). If the problem is in the `new $className` area it might be helpful to remove the `@` in the autoloader (lib\Varien\Autoload.php ~ line 94) so you can see some errors in your logs.